# MessageBox.Show Dialog Result / C# .NET 2017 Community

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a question box (MessageBox.Show) but I can't figure out how to get the Dialog Results. I looked at every posts, videos, but I can't seem to fine for the 2017 .NET (Wpf) version!

(Basically I want to make a question after InitializeComponents() )

Here is my code.

[image: (Code Here)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### WPF

If you're using WPF `MessageBox.Show()` does return a `MessageBoxResult`:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("asd", "xcvxcv", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    MessageBox.Show("Ok was selected");
```

#### Windows Forms

If you're using Windows Forms `MessageBox.Show()` does return a `DialogResult`:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("test", "bla bla", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    MessageBox.Show("Ok was selected");
```

#### Constructor could be a problem

I'm not an WPF expert, but there could be another problem: Your code-example shows that you're opening a `MessageBox` within your constructor. This can be a problem when showing your Form twice or if the code which handles your selection crashed.

Think about moving this to an Event when your Form is loaded:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.IsEnabled = false;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("asd", "xcvxcv", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        MessageBox.Show("Ok was selected");

    this.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This is working as intended. What problem do you have with it? You should post some code to clearify your problem.

Comment: @CassioTDSTheDiamondSword it doesn't work because its a guessing game at what you want, please update the question with more details, the code you have tried, and what you intend to achieve (before its closed)

Comment: First line, DialogResult is underlined red

Comment: @CassioTDSTheDiamondSword what type of application is this? winforms? wpf? web? what? There are, for example, 2 different `MessageBox.Show` methods, depending on which UI framework you're using; does `MessageBoxResult` work in place of `DialogResult`?

Comment: Post your code. Post all "using xxx" in your file. Underlines Red should show you an error-message in your "Error List" when trying to build your solution. Post these info ***to your question***

Comment: @kara note OP has now edited "WPF" into the question - not your fault (the answer pre-dates that edit), but you may wish to update to observe that (this answer is winforms, I believe); I *think* that just means changing `DialogResult` to `MessageBoxResult` and `MessageBoxButtons` to `MessageBoxButton` (no "s")

Comment: @MarcGravell Post this as a awnser ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. Did extend my post with example-code for WPF and WinForms